# Submodel Iteration Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I have the following Model which is working fine (1st image).

I'm running a Network Analyst Location-Allocation. I want to iterate both Facilities and Demand Locations.
So I'm calling a sub model (2nd image) to iterate the demand locations, which is stored as differents shapefiles within one folder.

However, when the model finishes it only used one shapefile from that folder and not all 4 shapefiles that it contains.

Can you figure out what I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the main model iterator is incrementing correctly but the sub-model is only returning a single shapefile? What happens when you run the sub-model by itself?

Comment: The submodel runs through my all 4 shapefiles which are within that folder

Comment: I think you should create a simple test model, in place of your larger model, and see if you can get that to iterate successfully.  Use something for your test that does not involve Network Analyst to widen the pool of potential answerers for your question.